# React component not rerendering based on props change. JSX in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a filterTime state which is set to "Daily" as default. It is located at the parent of Friends.js and passed as prop.

**Friends.js**

```
const Friends = (props) =>{
    const [friendsDisplay, setFriendsDisplay] = useState([]);
    let    friends = [];

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    const fetchData = async() => {
        try{
            let doc  = await docRef.get();
            let data = doc.data();

            for(let i of data.Friends){         //Getting the array of friends' uids
                friends.push(i);
            }

            friends = await Promise.all(friends.map(async UserFriend => {
                if(UserFriend !== ""){
                    let friend = await fetchUserFriendData(UserFriend);
                    return (<Friend key         = {UserFriend}
                                    UserFriend  = {friend} 
                                    isUser      = {false} 
                                    src         = {``}
                                    filterTime  = {props.filterTime}/>
                    )
                }
                return null;
            }));

            let userInfo = <Friend  key          = {uid}
                                    UserFriend  = {data}
                                    isUser      = {true}
                                    src         = {``}
                                    filterTime  = {props.filterTime}/>

            friends = friends.concat(userInfo);
            sortFriends();
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const sortFriends = () =>{
        if(friends.length !== 0){       //If User Has Friends Sorts Them in Descending Order
            friends.sort((a, b) => {
                if(props.filterTime === "Daily"){
                    return (a.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedToday > b.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedToday ? -1 : 1);
                }

                if(props.filterTime === "Weekly"){
                    return (a.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedWeek > b.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedWeek ? -1 : 1);
                }

                if(props.filterTime === "Monthly"){
                    return (a.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedMonth > b.props.UserFriend.XpEarnedMonth ? -1 : 1);
                }
                return -1;
            });
            setFriendsDisplay(friends);
        }

    return (
        <>
            <div className = "friendsContainer">
                {friendsDisplay.length !== 0 &&            //If User Has Friends (ScoreBoard)
                    <div className = "friends">{friendsDisplay}</div>
                }{friendsDisplay.length === 1 &&           //If User Has No Friends (Add Friend Button)
                    <>{friendsDisplay}</>
                }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

**Friend.js**

```
const Friend = (props) =>{    //filterTime---> Daily Weekly etc.  UserFriend--->all properties of friend  isUser--->boolean  src--->source for picture

    const[friendName, setFriendName] = useState(props.UserFriend.Name);
    let WindowWidth = windowResizeListener();

    return (
        <div className = {`friendBackground ${props.isUser ? "friendBackground-User" : ""}`}>
            <div className = "friendPorperties">
                <p className = {`friendRank ${props.isUser ? "friendRank-User" : ""}`}>1</p>
                <p className = {`friendName ${props.isUser ? "friendName-User" : ""}`}>{friendName}</p>
            </div>
            {props.filterTime === "Daily" &&                   //checks if filter = daily
                <p className = {`friendXp ${props.isUser ? "friendXp-User" : ""}`}>{`+${props.UserFriend.XpEarnedToday}Xp`}</p>
            }
            {props.filterTime === "Weekly" &&                   //checks if filter = weekly
                <p className = {`friendXp ${props.isUser ? "friendXp-User" : ""}`}>{`+${props.UserFriend.XpEarnedWeek}Xp`}</p>
            }
            {props.filterTime === "Monthly" &&                   //checks if filter = monthly
                <p className = {`friendXp ${props.isUser ? "friendXp-User" : ""}`}>{`+${props.UserFriend.XpEarnedMonth}Xp`}</p>
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I use;

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(props.filterTime);
    }, [props.filterTime])
```

In Friends.js it logs the correct filterTime value as I click different filters. Whereas in Friend.js it is stuck in the first value ("Daily") and won't update if I click different filters.

So the problem isn't about filterTime it is about child not rerendering as the filterTime value changes.
React Dev tools also shows prop.filterTime isn't changing for Friend.js.

How can I fix this.

Comment: As a general rule, you should only use JSX within the render/return. Most likely what is happening here is you're creating these component instances inside the `Promise.all` map, and the props value is stuck in a closure, so it's value is frozen for the lifecycle of the component. To fix it, restructure your code to not store component instances in state, but instead store the necessary data. Then map over it and create your components in the return statement

Comment: I would suggest something similar like @BrianThompson. Make a data structure with all the data you need in your API call and then use that with JSX. Fetch data should do one thing and compose your data in a separate function. Use all your JSX where rest of the JSX is and use your new data structure there to make the UI. Mixing fetching logic and jsx logic looks messy.

Comment: Thanks for your great replies. I will be trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

```
 friends = await Promise.all(friends.map(async UserFriend => {
                if(UserFriend !== ""){
                    let friend = await fetchUserFriendData(UserFriend);
                    return (<Friend key         = {UserFriend}
                                    UserFriend  = {friend} 
                                    isUser      = {false} 
                                    src         = {``}
                                    filterTime  = {props.filterTime ? props.filterTime : default}/>
                    )
                }
                return null;
            }));
```